# Does Coverity support xbuild (mono)?

Tags: c#, msbuild, mono, travis-ci, coverity

I've a C# project: https://github.com/Pro/dkim-exchange

It uses Travis CI: https://travis-ci.org/Pro/dkim-exchange

Travis successfully builds my project.

I wanted to set up Coverity to do automatic code quality measurements. For this I configured my `.travis.yml` as follows:

```
language: objective-c

env:
  global:
    - EnableNuGetPackageRestore=true
    # The next declaration is the encrypted COVERITY_SCAN_TOKEN, created
    #   via the "travis encrypt" command using the project repo's public key
    - secure: "kC7O0CWm9h4g+tzCwhIZEGwcdiLrb1/1PijeOKGbIWGuWS7cIksAkj2tRNMgtxxcE9CFQr8W7xDv2YzflCIlqN1nGkFjbyD4CrNg6+V1j0fZjPOQ6ssdBBVPrfrvecsAUJ0/48Tqa9VTkEpZSlwOF/VS1sO2ob36FVyWjtxvG9s="

  matrix:
    - MONO_VERSION="3.10.0"

install:
  # Fetch Mono
  - wget "http://download.mono-project.com/archive/${MONO_VERSION}/macos-10-x86/MonoFramework-MDK-${MONO_VERSION}.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg"
  - sudo installer -pkg "MonoFramework-MDK-${MONO_VERSION}.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg" -target /

script:
  - xbuild travis.proj

addons:
  coverity_scan:
    project:
      name: "Pro/dkim-exchange"
      description: "Build submitted via Travis CI"
    notification_email: mail@example.com
    build_command_prepend: "xbuild /t:CleanAll travis.proj"
    build_command:   "xbuild /t:Build travis.proj"
    branch_pattern: coverity_scan
```

If I execute the coverity build commands as indicated here (using msbuild): https://scan.coverity.com/download?tab=csharp the uploaded archive is analyzed correctly, but in combination with travis, the coverity analysis fails (see e.g. this build log: https://travis-ci.org/Pro/dkim-exchange/builds/42295611).
There's this warning:

```
[WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with your configuration

or because no files were actually compiled by your build command.

Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation.
```

I think this may be related to xbuild from Mono. Unfortunately Dr. Google didn't find anythin about Coverity+xbuild. **Does Coverity support xbuild? If yes, how can I correctly setup the project?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to C#, Coverity actually only supports msbuild.

You can find some more official information about this in the following

- http://www.coverity.com/library/pdf/CoverityStaticAnalysis.pdf
- https://communities.coverity.com/message/6251#6251

The last link explicitly states

> *Our C# analysis only supports the Visual Studio C# compilers*

So, no xbuild support as of now.

### Update:

When you **[download](https://scan.coverity.com/download)** the Coverity build tool, the `doc/en/help/cov-build.txt` explicitly states the following:

> *C# build capture is only supported on Windows.*